# Exporting equation result on RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a dosing calculator and thought I had it all figured out but keep on getting "Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator". I suspect that the error might be on the way the variables are added but figured that as.numeric() would solve that issue which it didn't.

My current code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    sliderInput("dose.ml", "Enter dose in ml",min=0, max=100, value=50,step = 1),
    radioButtons("size", "Size of bottle in ml", list(50,100), ""),
    selectInput("total.mg", "Mg per bottle", c(1000,2000,3000), selected = 2000),
    submitButton("Submit"),
    textOutput("dose.mg")
))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  output$dose.mg <- renderText({
    X <- input$dose.ml
    Y <- input$size
    Z <- input$total.mg
    paste("The result is =", ((X/Y)*Z), "mg")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the text output of text widgets to numeric values:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    sliderInput("dose.ml", "Enter dose in ml",min = 0, max = 100, value = 50, step = 1),
    radioButtons("size", "Size of bottle in ml", list(50, 100)),
    selectInput("total.mg", "mg per bottle", c(1000, 2000, 3000), selected = 2000),
    #submitButton("Submit"),
    textOutput("dose.mg")
  ))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  output$dose.mg <- renderText({
    X <- input$dose.ml
    Y <- as.numeric(input$size)
    Z <- as.numeric(input$total.mg)
    paste("The result is =", X/Y * Z, "mg")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Two suggestions:

- you may consider to get rid of the "Submit" button. The calculation is fast, so that calculations can be done immediately.
- the radio button should also have a default.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert `as.integer()` `X`, `Y`, and `Z`:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    sliderInput("dose.ml", "Enter dose in ml",min=0, max=100, value=50,step = 1),
    radioButtons("size", "Size of bottle in ml", list(50,100), ""),
    selectInput("total.mg", "Mg per bottle", c(1000,2000,3000), selected = 2000),
    submitButton("Submit"),
    textOutput("dose.mg")
  ))
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  output$dose.mg <- renderText({
    X <- as.integer(input$dose.ml)
    Y <- as.integer(input$size)
    Z <- as.integer(input$total.mg)
    paste("The result is =", ((X/Y)*Z), "mg")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]